# Autorefresh multiple pivot tables when queried and calculated data sheet changes

Tags: vba, excel, pivot, pivot-table

I have one data sheet ("Data") with Columns A:K pulled from a query and Columns L:O calculating information from the A:K.

I have two pivot table sheets ("PT-Day", "PT-Wk") with two separate pivot tables (Both called "PivotTable5") that reference the "Data" information.

The Data connection is set to refresh every 5 minutes. I need both pivot tables to refresh when anything on the Data sheet changes.

I have tried the following code in the Data tab.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Worksheets("PT-Day").PivotTables("PivotTable5").PivotCache.Refresh
    Worksheets("PT-Wk").PivotTables("PivotTable5").PivotCache.Refresh
End Sub
```

And I receive a Subscript out of Range error on Line 02. I also tried a new data tab without calculated columns and using the above code - same result. Help please?

Comment: you need to set the `PivotCache` to the updated data source, are you doing it somewhere else in your code ?

Comment: @ShaiRado would this also not work to create a refresh upon event, e.g. when the value of a cell is changed on whatever specific sheet?  I am not familiar with the PivotCache, so my apologies if this seems redundant or is just incorrect.

Comment: `ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll`.

Comment: @ShaiRado I'm not sure what you mean. I am not referencing the PivotCache anywhere else in the code.

Comment: how are your `PivotTables` connected to your worksheets data ? to the entire columns("A:K") , or Range("A1:K500") ? I chose 500 for example ?

Comment: @ShaiRado The pivot tables reference the table query. The data source says "Table_Query_From_Sql1_I1234

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Did you finally solve it?

Comment: @AbhishekSingh I ended up putting the following code on my queried data sheet. It worked. 

`Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
End Sub`

Comment: Did this part work for you? 
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

    'If data on this worksheet changes, refresh the pivot table
    Sheets("Pivot").PivotTables("PivotTable1").RefreshTable

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

I tried this my data was on 1 sheet and 2 other sheets had pivot table. The first pivot sheet table was refreshed because of the command and then eventually the second sheet. See if this works for you.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

    'If data on this worksheet changes, refresh the pivot table
    Sheets("Pivot").PivotTables("PivotTable1").RefreshTable

End Sub
```